# When using "IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT..." in Sql Server, does it matter which columns you choose?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quite a lot of database scripts are of the form:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Countries WHERE Name = 'France')
INSERT INTO(Countries)
```

However, I've also seen people do:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT CountryID FROM Countries WHERE Name = 'France')
INSERT INTO(Countries)
```

And even:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Countries WHERE Name = 'France')
INSERT INTO(Countries)
```

The advantage of the last one is supposedly that its more efficient: the query doesn't actually use any of the columns in the subquery, so it might be quicker to not bring any of them back.  But it looks odd, so it strikes me that it might confuse some people. And does it make any difference anyway to the actual execution time?

Comment: I commonly use the latter one as you indeed don't need any of the fields from the subquery. I couldn't tell about performance (cfr answers...apparently no impact on perf), but I don't find the syntax very disturbing, at least when you'v seen it once.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it was back in the 6.5 - 7 period of SQL Server that they made the query optimizer smart enough to know that:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Countries WHERE Name = 'France')
```

Does not actually need to return any row data. The advice to use `SELECT 1` pre-dates that, yet continues on as a myth.

Arguably, it's a fault with the SQL standard - they ought to allow `EXISTS` to start with the `FROM` clause and not have a `SELECT` portion at all.

---

And from [Subqueries with EXISTS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189259%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> The select list of a subquery introduced by EXISTS almost always consists of an asterisk (*). There is no reason to list column names because you are just testing whether rows that meet the conditions specified in the subquery exist.

Comment: I continue to use `SELECT 1` for self-documentation purposes. I can see by looking only at the subquery that it doesn't return data.

Comment: Ok, I guess thats the answer then - its just a matter of personal preference.  Personally I prefer SELECT *, but I can see that some people might think SELECT 1 is more logical.

Answer (score 3):

No,
sql server is smart enough to make this optimization for you.

Answer (score 3):

No. The only thing that matters is if rows are returned or not, That's why SELECT 1 is good enough.